# What does ax.containers[0] represent?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a barplot in Seaborn, and based on the tutorials I’ve seen ax.containers[0] seems to contain all the data points in the Axes. But I was wondering, what type of object anre those data points? Also, is there a containers[1]? Sorry if this is a simple question, but I’ve searched a lot and never found a description of what exactly containers[0] is and what it contains.

Comment: As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804)